# how to close oracle connection when network gets disconnected in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on Transaction Management of multiple inline queries if Connection Loss due to network disconnectivity between any query all other transaction should be rollback which works fine but exception throws ORA-12571 encountered.
oracle session goes in inactive state not killed and that particaular record is struck(can not be updated untill manually kill the session)

Comment: The network error has terminated your connection to the database server. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jonny database session becomes inactive and that particular record on which the connection is lost is stuck and can't be updated or deleted until the session is killed manually in PLSQL Developer. How can we kill the session when transaction is not completed (transaction is rolledback).